# Getting a batch file to run in task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have a batch file that, when run, will append the date and time to the end of a file.    However, when this is run via Task Scheduler, it does not append the date/time to the end of the file.

The batch file in question:

```
@echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log="E:\PowerEQ\Logs\website.log" /ini=nul ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://<hiddeninfo>/" ^
    "lcd E:\Website\" ^
    "cd /public_html/powereq/processed/" ^
    "get test.zip" ^
"exit"
cd\
cd Website

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set 
dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH%%Min%%Sec%


rename "test.zip" "test_%stamp%.zip"
    "exit" ^
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working when run with Task Scheduler?

Comment: hard to say as you didn't explain how it was setup in the task scheduler.  Is It running under an account that has permissions to the file?

Comment: Is the E: drive a local drive or a mapped network path?  Is the scheduled task setup to run when the user is logged in or run whether user is logged on or not?

Comment: It's setup to run whether the user is logged on or not, using local server administrator account.  The E: drive is local drive.

I have a similar batch file (same as this one without the date component) that runs through task scheduler just fine.

Comment: @BrianRudnicke, when you setup task scheduler like that the default working directory becomes the SYSTEM32 directory when the batch file is executed.  When you use the `CD` command it is working off of the C: drive.  Change your your `CD` command to. `CD /D E:\website`

Answer (score 0):

To debug problem like this, wrap the batch file to another one with an output redirected to a file.

Wrapper batch file (e.g. `wrapper.bat`) will be like:

```
C:\path\to\thebatch.bat > C:\writtable\path\thebatch.log 2>&1
```

And execute the `wrapper.bat` from Task Scheduler, instead of `thebatch.bat`.

Then inspect the log file for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I setup the wrapper.bat as instructed, but it's only garnering the output of the transfer program WinSCP.  Anything executed after that is not logged.

Comment: I've forgot to add error redirection. See my updated answer.